# module 'tensorlayer.layers' has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a binarised neural network but error is
"module 'tensorlayer.layers' has no attribute 'flatten'"

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, 48, 1])
net = tl.layers.InputLayer(x, name='input')
net = tl.layers.BinaryConv2d(net, 32, (5, 5), (1, 1), padding='SAME', name='bcnn1')
net = tl.layers.MaxPool2d(net, (2, 2), (2, 2), padding='SAME', name='pool1')
net = tl.layers.BatchNormLayer(net, act=tl.act.htanh, is_train=True,name='bn1')
net = tl.layers.SignLayer(net)
net = tl.layers.BinaryConv2d(net, 64, (5, 5), (1, 1), padding='SAME', name='bcnn2')
net = tl.layers.MaxPool2d(net, (2, 2), (2, 2), padding='SAME', name='pool2')
net = tl.layers.BatchNormLayer(net, act=tl.act.htanh, is_train=True, name='bn2')
net = tl.layers.flatten(net)
net = tl.layers.DenseLayer(net, n_units=40, act = tf.identity, name='output_layer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not `flatten` attribute. You're looking for the [`FlattenLayer`](https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/layers.html#tensorlayer.layers.FlattenLayer) attribute:

```
net = tl.layers.FlattenLayer(net)
```